# Can't get SQL Server 2012 Express EULA to suppress (despite using /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms) with Visual Studio 2015 prerequisite install

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation, sql-server-express, bootstrapper

I have a setup project in Visual Studio 2015 for my .NET Windows Forms project that needs SQL Server 2012 Express as a prerequisite. I have successfully created a bootstrapper (located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2012`) and added the following command to make it silent:

```
/q /action=Install /features=SQL,AS,RS,IS,Tools 
/instancename=SQLExpress /sqlsvcaccount="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
/sqlsysadminaccounts="BUILTIN\Users" 
/agtsvcaccount="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
/IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck`
```

however I still get the EULA popup despite having `/IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms`.

The `install.log` indicates that the command is indeed being applied (and the fact it does install silently, just after I have to click on the EULA).  What gives? I'm  confused on how it picks up all the rest of the command but ignores the `/IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms`.

The only theory I have is that it first calls `SqlExpressChk.exe` to determine whether to install the x32 or x64 bit version, and the EULA is attached to that. Any thoughts?

Here's the install.log line indicating my command is indeed being applied:

```
Installing using command 'C:\Users\ljhersma\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD11B8.tmp\SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE' and parameters '/qs /action=Install /features=SQL,AS,RS,IS,Tools /instancename=SQLExpress /sqlsvcaccount="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /sqlsysadminaccounts="BUILTIN\Users" /agtsvcaccount="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /ENABLERANU /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck'
```

Comment: /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms=true ? By the way in MSDN is spelled all in uppercase /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS

Comment: I actually just got done trying `/IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms`, `/IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms=true`, `/IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms=True`, and `/IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms=1` and none worked.  The documentation does make it pretty clear that `/IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms` should default to true. EDIT: Caps didn't work either.

Comment: You could try IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES if the application will use the native client

Comment: @benni_mac_b Thanks for the suggestion, tried it out and no dice unfortunately.